# Trying to create a material for to apply a texture on a game model

Tags: texturing

I've followed a guide to import an SFM model into Blender. I've got the .MDL decompiled and into Blender, but I just cannot find a way to apply the texture that comes along with it onto the model. I've tried hitting the texture button and adding a texture, but that doesn't work.
[image]

The skeleton doesn't have that ball icon for me to click to make a new material so I can put the texture on. The only other thing that the model came with is are the VTA vertices, but they don't help in the way of putting textures on the actual model.
So how and what do I apply a texture to?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the thing is that you're using cycles but are not using the nodes to actually apply the image texture, you can do it like this:

Select the model in object mode -> go to materials -> select the material->go to node editor
[image]

After that, check the box use nodes

[image]

It'll look like this, then you have to create an image texture node by pressing SHIFT + A and click search, search for image texture, after that you only have to select the image you already have in the .blend file:

[image]

Hope this helps!